# Problem in understanding Riemann's removable singularity theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> **Theorem** $:$ Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in the region $\Omega' \subseteq \Omega$ which is obtained from $\Omega$ by a removing a single point $a \in \Omega.$ Then $f$ has a unique holomorphic extension to $\Omega$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{z \to a} (z - a) f(z) = 0.$

Uniqueness clearly follows from the fact that if the extension exists it is continuous at $a.$ It is also easy to see that the condition is necessary. In order to prove the condition is sufficient what Ahlfors did is the following $:$

> Consider a circle $C$ around $a$ such that $C$ along with its interior is contained in $\Omega.$ Then by Cauchy's integral formula combined with homotopy version of Cauchy's theorem it follows that for all $z \neq a$ in the interior of $C$ $$f(z) = \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac {f(\zeta)} {\zeta - z}\ d\zeta.$$ Also since $f$ is continuous on $C,$ it turns out that the right hand side is holomorphic inside $C.$ Consequently, the function which equals to $f(z)$ for $z \neq a$ and $$\frac{1} {2 \pi i}\int_{C} \frac {f(\zeta)} {\zeta - a}\ d\zeta$$ at $z = a$ is a holomorphic extension of $f$ to $\Omega.$ $\square$

I understand the idea of the proof. The only part where I am wondering is that where did the author apply the hypothesis $\lim\limits_{z \to a} (z - a) f(z) = 0$ in the proof? I can clearly see that without that assumption the idea of extending a function holomorphically won't work. Simply consider the function $f : \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $f(z) = \frac {1} {z},$ $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Then the function $f$ does not admit holomorphic extension to $\mathbb C$ simply because $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} |f(z)| = \infty.$ So the author should have used the hypothesis somewhere in the proof which I am unable to figure out. Any small suggestion regarding this would be highly solicited.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: why is it that are you allowed to apply CIF directly to $f(z)$ in the block quote but trying to do that with $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ fails?

Comment: @user8675309$:$ That is also my question. If you apply CIF for the function $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ then you get $0$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$ (again as a consequence of CIF). So CIF miserably fails here. I would like to know the reason for that. You can find the verbatim proof in Ahlfors' book in complex analysis which compels me to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahlfors refers specifically to Theorem 3 in the words leading up to this theorem. You should pay attention to that and apply that theorem. That theorem tells us that with the given boundedness hypothesis at $z=a$ and holomorphicity elsewhere, the Cauchy theorem ($\int_{\partial R} f(z)\,dz = 0$) still holds.

Comment: For $z \neq a$ inside $C$ we can apply Theorem $5$ to the function $F(\zeta) = \frac {f(\zeta) -f(z)} {\zeta - z}$ which is holomorphic for $\zeta \neq z$ and $\lim\limits_{\zeta \to z} (\zeta - z) F(\zeta) = \lim\limits_{\zeta \to z} (f(\zeta) - f(z)) = 0$ and hence the result follows from Theorem $5.$ That should give the expression for CIF. Right?

Comment: But still the hypothesis is not being used.

Comment: Of course the hypothesis is being used, as the function is not holomorphic at $a$, which is still inside your region.

Comment: Oh! Got it. $F$ is not defined at $\zeta = a.$ That's why we need the hypothesis to hold in order to apply Theorem $5.$ There are two problematic points here. One is $z$ and the other one is $a.$ So we need boundedness argument for both the points. Boundedness for $F$ near $z \neq a$ is inbuilt by the continuity of $f$ at $z.$ So we only need boundedness of $F$ near $a$ which is being taken care of by the given hypothesis. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Glad it finally makes sense. By the way, this section of Ahlfors is one I never liked or followed when I taught courses based on the book. I preferred to discuss this theorem after developing the Laurent expansion.